# Maven Tomcat Plugin: can't deploy to server

Tags: maven, tomcat, maven-tomcat-plugin

My environment: Windows 8.1 -> Tomcat 7.0.59 -> Maven 3.2.5.

I have a ready project which I can compile, get a war-file, copy to %TOMCAT_HOME%\webapps, start the Tomcat and run my app, all works. But I want setup autodeploy. I add a plugin in my **pom.xml**:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
        <server>MyTomcat</server>
        <path>/foxrestful</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then in **%TOMCAT_HOME%\conf\tomcat-users.xml** I added:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <role rolename="manager"/>
    <user username="admin" password="11qqsd" roles="admin-gui,admin,manager,manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status"/>    
</tomcat-users>
```

In **%MAVEN_HOME\conf\settings.xml%** and in **C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.m2\settings.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <pluginGroups>
  </pluginGroups>
  <proxies>
  </proxies>
  <servers>   
    <server>
        <id>MyTomcat</id>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>11qqsd</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
  </mirrors>  
  <profiles>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

Then I add a Maven Tomcat plugin in my **pom.xml** file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
        <server>MyTomcat</server>
        <path>/foxrestful</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For check my settings I start Tomcat, open *http://localhost:8080/manager/html*, enter login: *admin*, password: *11qqsd* and Tomcat show me manager app panel. It's work!

When I execute **in console**

```
mvn tomcat7:deploy
```

I get:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building foxrestful 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) > package @ foxrestful >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ foxrestful ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ foxrestful ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ foxrestful ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory e:\Compilers\Projects\Java\JerseyRESTful\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ foxrestful ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ foxrestful ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (default-war) @ foxrestful ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [foxrestful] in [e:\Compilers\Projects\Java\JerseyRESTful\target\foxrestful]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [e:\Compilers\Projects\Java\JerseyRESTful\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [170 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: e:\Compilers\Projects\Java\JerseyRESTful\target\foxrestful.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) < package @ foxrestful <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) @ foxrestful ---
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/foxrestful  
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/html/deploy?path=%2Ffoxrestful
2/11111 KB   
4/11111 KB   
6/11111 KB   
8/11111 KB   
10/11111 KB   
12/11111 KB   
14/11111 KB   
16/11111 KB   
18/11111 KB   
20/11111 KB   
22/11111 KB   
24/11111 KB   
26/11111 KB   
28/11111 KB   
30/11111 KB   
32/11111 KB   
34/11111 KB   
36/11111 KB   
38/11111 KB   
40/11111 KB   
42/11111 KB   
44/11111 KB   
46/11111 KB   
48/11111 KB   
50/11111 KB   
52/11111 KB   
54/11111 KB   
56/11111 KB   
58/11111 KB   
60/11111 KB   
62/11111 KB   
64/11111 KB   
66/11111 KB   
68/11111 KB   
70/11111 KB   
72/11111 KB   
74/11111 KB   
76/11111 KB   
78/11111 KB   
80/11111 KB   
82/11111 KB   
84/11111 KB   
86/11111 KB   
88/11111 KB   
90/11111 KB   
92/11111 KB   
94/11111 KB   
96/11111 KB   
98/11111 KB   
100/11111 KB   
102/11111 KB   
104/11111 KB   
106/11111 KB   
108/11111 KB   
110/11111 KB   
112/11111 KB   
114/11111 KB   
116/11111 KB   
118/11111 KB   
120/11111 KB   
122/11111 KB   
124/11111 KB   
126/11111 KB   
128/11111 KB   
130/11111 KB   
132/11111 KB   
134/11111 KB   
136/11111 KB   
138/11111 KB   
140/11111 KB   
142/11111 KB   
144/11111 KB   
146/11111 KB   
148/11111 KB   
150/11111 KB   
152/11111 KB   
154/11111 KB   
156/11111 KB   
158/11111 KB   
160/11111 KB   
162/11111 KB   
164/11111 KB   
166/11111 KB   
168/11111 KB   
170/11111 KB   
172/11111 KB   
174/11111 KB   
176/11111 KB   
178/11111 KB   
180/11111 KB   
182/11111 KB   
184/11111 KB   
186/11111 KB   
188/11111 KB   
190/11111 KB   
192/11111 KB   

[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/html/deploy?path=%2Ffoxrestful
2/11111 KB   
4/11111 KB   
6/11111 KB   
8/11111 KB   
10/11111 KB   
12/11111 KB   
14/11111 KB   
16/11111 KB   
18/11111 KB   
20/11111 KB   
22/11111 KB   
24/11111 KB   
26/11111 KB   
28/11111 KB   
30/11111 KB   
32/11111 KB   
34/11111 KB   
36/11111 KB   
38/11111 KB   
40/11111 KB   
42/11111 KB   
44/11111 KB   
46/11111 KB   
48/11111 KB   
50/11111 KB   
52/11111 KB   
54/11111 KB   
56/11111 KB   
58/11111 KB   
60/11111 KB   
62/11111 KB   
64/11111 KB   
66/11111 KB   
68/11111 KB   
70/11111 KB   
72/11111 KB   
74/11111 KB   
76/11111 KB   
78/11111 KB   
80/11111 KB   
82/11111 KB   
84/11111 KB   
86/11111 KB   
88/11111 KB   
90/11111 KB   
92/11111 KB   
94/11111 KB   
96/11111 KB   
98/11111 KB   
100/11111 KB   
102/11111 KB   
104/11111 KB   
106/11111 KB   
108/11111 KB   
110/11111 KB   
112/11111 KB   
114/11111 KB   
116/11111 KB   
118/11111 KB   
120/11111 KB   

[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/html/deploy?path=%2Ffoxrestful
2/11111 KB   
4/11111 KB   
6/11111 KB   
8/11111 KB   
10/11111 KB   
12/11111 KB   
14/11111 KB   
16/11111 KB   
18/11111 KB   
20/11111 KB   
22/11111 KB   
24/11111 KB   
26/11111 KB   
28/11111 KB   
30/11111 KB   
32/11111 KB   
34/11111 KB   
36/11111 KB   
38/11111 KB   
40/11111 KB   
42/11111 KB   
44/11111 KB   
46/11111 KB   
48/11111 KB   
50/11111 KB   
52/11111 KB   
54/11111 KB   
56/11111 KB   
58/11111 KB   
60/11111 KB   
62/11111 KB   
64/11111 KB   
66/11111 KB   
68/11111 KB   
70/11111 KB   
72/11111 KB   
74/11111 KB   
76/11111 KB   
78/11111 KB   
80/11111 KB   
82/11111 KB   
84/11111 KB   
86/11111 KB   
88/11111 KB   
90/11111 KB   
92/11111 KB   
94/11111 KB   
96/11111 KB   
98/11111 KB   
100/11111 KB   
102/11111 KB   
104/11111 KB   
106/11111 KB   
108/11111 KB   
110/11111 KB   
112/11111 KB   
114/11111 KB   
116/11111 KB   
118/11111 KB   
120/11111 KB   
122/11111 KB   
124/11111 KB   
126/11111 KB   
128/11111 KB   
130/11111 KB   
132/11111 KB   
134/11111 KB   
136/11111 KB   
138/11111 KB   
140/11111 KB   

[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/html/deploy?path=%2Ffoxrestful
2/11111 KB   
4/11111 KB   
6/11111 KB   
8/11111 KB   
10/11111 KB   
12/11111 KB   
14/11111 KB   
16/11111 KB   
18/11111 KB   
20/11111 KB   
22/11111 KB   
24/11111 KB   
26/11111 KB   
28/11111 KB   
30/11111 KB   
32/11111 KB   
34/11111 KB   
36/11111 KB   
38/11111 KB   
40/11111 KB   
42/11111 KB   
44/11111 KB   
46/11111 KB   
48/11111 KB   
50/11111 KB   
52/11111 KB   
54/11111 KB   
56/11111 KB   
58/11111 KB   
60/11111 KB   
62/11111 KB   
64/11111 KB   
66/11111 KB   
68/11111 KB   
70/11111 KB   
72/11111 KB   
74/11111 KB   
76/11111 KB   
78/11111 KB   
80/11111 KB   
82/11111 KB   
84/11111 KB   
86/11111 KB   
88/11111 KB   
90/11111 KB   
92/11111 KB   
94/11111 KB   
96/11111 KB   
98/11111 KB   
100/11111 KB   
102/11111 KB   
104/11111 KB   
106/11111 KB   
108/11111 KB   
110/11111 KB   
112/11111 KB   
114/11111 KB   
116/11111 KB   
118/11111 KB   
120/11111 KB   
122/11111 KB   
124/11111 KB   
126/11111 KB   
128/11111 KB   
130/11111 KB   
132/11111 KB   

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.210 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-18T17:28:50+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/210M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project foxrestful: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection reset by peer: socket write error -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Can anyone say me what i did wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356477/tomcat-7-connection-reset-by-peer-or-software-caused-connection-abort (take especially note of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26621807/875083)

Comment: I find error. I so stupid that i type wrong URL for Maven Tomcat Plugin. Worked for me when url config in pom.xml i changed to http://localhost:8080/manager/text

Question closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using 
http://localhost:8080/manager/text instead of 
http://localhost:8080/manager/html

Additionally user should not be granted manager-gui,manager-script roles at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

In the pom fie plugin configuration, use this:

```
<configuration>
    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
    <server>MyTomcat</server>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>11qqsd</password>
    <path>/foxrestful</path>
</configuration>
```

You have to change the URL to `manager/text` nstead of `manager/html`.
If changing it alone didn't work, add `<username>` and `<password>` also to the plugin configuration, and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

try this "mvn tomcat7:redeploy" command

Comment: What's the difference between `mvn tomcat7:deploy` and `mvn tomcat7:redeploy`?

Comment: I wrote that i solve my problem. Read the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

something wrong with tomcat-user.xml.

```
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="pwd" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,admin-script,admin-gui"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did solve the issue by putting username/password inside the pom file.

However, I would like to know why it didn't work if I want to configure username/password at maven setttings.xml only.

Anyone have idea about it ?

Thanks

Comment: Please use the answer section to post clear and direct answers to the question. Any questions or comments you have can be posted in the comments section.

Comment: If you're using Intellij, please note that there is a %intellij-path%/plugins/maven directory that has it's own settings.xml.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the error

Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Run as Administrator start two separate command prompt terminals. In the first terminal, go to your tomcat bin dir & run shutdown.bat & thereafter startup.bat in my case

c:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.8\bin>shutdown.bat

c:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.8\bin>startup.bat

In the second terminal, go to your maven webapp dir then run the mvn command. In my case

mvn tomcat7:deploy

It will be a BUILD SUCCESS!!!